# How do I sum up a score based on 2 values?

Tags: excel, countif

I have this excel table

```
Status | Priority |
-------------------
Yes    | High     |
No     | Medium   |
N/A    | Medium   |
Yes    | Low      |
A bit  | Bonus    |
       |          |
       |          |
```

Each priority has a point value. Priority points can change to anything. They aren't in order. Note that lines can also be blank. Assuming that if priority is blank then status is also blank.

```
High = 3 points
Medium = 2 Points
Low = 1 Point
Bonus = 1 Point
```

Status's can be blank or any value. However if they are the following then they have coniditions:

```
Yes = Full point (eg. Yes with High priority gives 3 points) or (eg. Yes with Bonus gives 1 point).
A bit = Half a point (eg. A little with High priortiy gives half 1.5 points) or (eg. A little with Medium gives 1 point). Essentially halving the point.
```

If the `Status` is `Yes` then I want it to count the corresponding point value. So for the table above it should count up 4.5 points.

```
3 Points for Row 2
1 Point for Row 5
0.5 points for Row 6
```

I was wondering how I can do this?
I was going to do the following, but it only has one condition.

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A5, "Yes")
```

Comment: You need to fix your question and show all possibilities. We can only write formula to what you have shown and asked. If we do not know we need to account for something how are we supposed to adjust the formula.  For those that cannot see, I just deleted my answer because the OP kept changing the requirements.

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried to be as clear as I can. Edited my post

Answer (score 1):

Using Tables and Named Ranges with structured references gives you a great deal of flexibility.

I first set up two tables

**priorityTbl**

[image]

**statusTbl**

[image]

With our Input, I **Named** the two Ranges `Status` and `Priority`

[image]

The total is then given by the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(INDEX(statusTbl,MATCH(Status,statusTbl[Status],0),2),0),
IFERROR(INDEX(priorityTbl,MATCH(Priority,priorityTbl[Priority],0),2),0))
```

If you want to change the values you assign to the different `Priority/Status` items, you merely change them in the table.

You could also add new rows to the tables, if that is appropriate.

Note that I did not bother adding to the tables rows where the value might be zero, but you could if you wanted to.

Comment: I've tried doing this. I named my tables and my ranges but the answer I get is 0

Comment: @Jackie Works fine here. Review your exact steps. Try confirming the formula by holding down Ctrl+shift while hitting Enter. Try using regular cell references.

Comment: @Jackie If you want to upload your file as an `*.xlsx` to some public sharing site, and post a link, I'll take a look at it.